# nested substr php

Tags: php, arrays, nested, substr

Hell all,

I'm trying to make my code cleaner, can you guys please le tme know if the following actually works. From my test, I can't seem to tell becaues it goes off and on with the matches. Please help and thank you in advance.

```
$minar=array('1','2','9','0');
if ($phpmins>"2" && in_array(substr($phpmins, -1),$minar) && $phpmins<$newmax)
```

The part I'm worrying about is: `&& in_array(substr($phpmins, -1),$minar)`

Can you nest the substr in the in_array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `substr` returns a value which is then passed to `in_array` as the first parameter. These are all equivalent in this respect:

```
in_array('foo', $minar)
in_array($var, $minar)
in_array(someFunction(), $minar)
```

Those are the basic rules of programming and values/variables/function return values.